# Why is the NTFS compression setting ignored by some applications?

Tags: ntfs, compression

I use NTFS compression on some folders, I understand the pros and cons of this, but for my use case it is preferred.

I have noticed some odd behavior for many years.  Some applications do not "honor" the directory compression flag.

I have never been able to determine why this is so.  I'd like to understand the reasons and if there is any way to "force" and application to honor it.

Currently I just use a batch that runs compact from time to time on the required folders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean that the `compression` checkbox is unchecked altogether?

Probably what's happening is that those applications are creating files somewhere else then moving them into the destination folder.  A move on the same partition won't force the compression to be applied because of the new parent.

Comment: You were right.  The move is what was causing it.  Much of the time it is a move from the %TMP% directory.

Comment: A move also won’t respect the permissions.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Only on XP. Vista and 7 apply permissions of the target on moves now.

Comment: @afrazier Only if you have „easy file sharing”. The filesystem hasn’t changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some folders and core system files will ignore the NTFS compression flag.

**Only if the option was enabled in the drive settings and not explicitly on a folder or file**

The windows OS controls this. For example `NTLDR, NTDETECT.COM, HIBERFIL.SYS` files are ignored. Also boot files are ignored. But if you were to explicitly enable compression it would break boot.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071127-00/?p=24373